# html5 tag video download button not working in app

Tags: html, ember.js

The download button in html5 video tag is not working in ember-cordova mobile app.

I have tested it on both web and chrome in mobile and it is working perfectly. Its just not downloading in app. Any ideas on how to fix this?

I have tried adding the storage permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and it is not working too.

Here is the code below.

```
<video id={{item.id}} class="social-video" {{action goToDiscuss item.id}} poster={{convert-url item.post_image}}>
<source src={{convert-url item.post_image.web_url}} type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE.

Comment: Hi, I am having the same issue. Have you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I can not add a comment because I have enough reputation. You just need to be added write permission on external or internal storage then You will be able to download the video. add plugin storage and get permission on run time while download video.